# SendKeys isn't working with variables

Tags: variables, vbscript, runtime-error, sendkeys

I wrote a very simple VBS program such that a different program can call it, in order to use the `SendKeys` method. When I just write out a simple string to test it like so:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys "testing"
```

it works just fine. But when I use an equivalent variable in place of the string like so:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set thingy = "testing"

WshShell.SendKeys thingy
```

it gives the following error when called:

[image: Error in line 2: Object required: '[string: "testing"]']

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with `set thingy = "testing"`, not with the `SendKeys`. [`Set` statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4afksd44%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) are for assigning objects to variables. They must not be used for assigning primitive data types.

Use `thingy = "testing"` instead.

Comment: I do not understand. because I am not using `Set`